# Data in msp430 flash was lost

Tags: memory, msp430, iar, flash-memory

Hi，I am using **MSP430F5340** MCU and my IDE is **IAR workbench**，today after adding some lines of code, I found my data that previously stored in flash was crashed. So I supposed the code memory size in flash has gone beyond the data flash boundary.

This MCU has total 64K flash (`0xFFFF` bytes), my data start address is `0xF400`，and ends at `0xF9FF`，totally 3 blocks of 0.5K bytes. So from `0x0000` up to `0xF400` (61K) is for code area.

[Flash Allocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J3sI.png)

[image]

From the last lines of map file,I found something below:
41196 bytes of CODE memory
3022 bytes of DATA memory (+ 83 absolute )
5421 bytes of CONST memory

`41,196 + 3,022 + 5,421` < 61K bytes, so how is it possible that my own data in flash memory was crashed?

Previously, when my data was not influenced,the map file shows:
39 478 bytes of CODE  memory
3 022 bytes of DATA  memory (+ 83 absolute )
4 755 bytes of CONST memory

I wonder the code memory starting address is not 0x00，and after adding some lines,the code area just cover the data area.

Hope someone could help to explain me this matter.

I think this question invovles both on firmware and hardware section,so I post it both places.

The two maps files and MSP430F5340 datasheet were attched.

Map File1(Data is right): https://drive.google.com/file/d/13g3YaZKI10u1q55rDdmwMBhIGRPOl71d/view?usp=sharing

Map File2(Data is wrong): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l5opnbOKgD1kPARb_j0NY6KI2WhXvE9J/view?usp=sharing

Msp430F5340: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1De8R4SqtLIoAC6_SqyonO0Nbdk6oP29L/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/508322/why-my-data-in-msp430-flash-was-lost.

Comment: yeah,i post this question both places

Comment: The summary only lists the number of bytes used The intersting part of the map file is "SEGMENTS IN ADDRESS ORDER". If you look in Map File 1 you see that the <CODE> 1 segement ends at address F055 while in Map File 2 it ends on F9A5.

Comment: Thank u so much,a big hint to this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Already solved this issue.
The key point is,from the link file 'lnk430f5340.xcl',I found the flash memory allocation for code area is 0x4400-0xFF7F & 0x10000-0x143FF。
And the code size is '41196 bytes of CODE memory' + '5421 bytes of CONST memory'('3022 bytes of DATA memory' should in RAM)
thus the data at 0xF400 was lost.
There are 2 ways to solve it.
1).Put the data to the larger address,for example at 0x13600
2).Modify memory allocation for code area,change it to 0x4400-0xFF3F & 0x10000-0x143FF,so the data at 0xF400 will not be covered.